# Calculate $\int\limits_0^3 x^{-3/5}(3-x)^{-3/5} dx$

Tags: integration, gamma-function

Calculate an integral
$$
\int\limits_0^3 x^{-3/5}(3-x)^{-3/5} dx.
$$
I know it may be done using gamma-function. But I can't find the appropriate substitute.

Comment: How about $x=3u$?

Comment: The Beta function.

Comment: Let $x=3\sin^2t$

Comment: no solution in elementary functions can be found

Comment: Yes, you are correct, it can be done using gamma-function.

Comment: $x=3u$ works, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you set $x=3u$, you get

$$3^{-1/5}\int_0^1u^{-3/5}(1-u)^{-3/5}\ du$$

Which is clearly a Beta integral, though the result does not simplify much.

$$\frac{[\Gamma(2/5)]^2}{\sqrt[5]{3}\Gamma(4/5)}$$